# Is there any direct way to copy one s3 directory to another in java or scala?

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to archive all the files and sub directories in a s3 directory to some other s3 location using java. Is there any direct way to copy one s3 directory to another in java or scala?

Comment: There is no such thing as an s3 directory. S3 is a key-value store. Suppose your key is "/a/b/c/foo.bar". That doesn't mean there is a directory called "a", and inside it a directory called "b", and inside it "c", and inside it "foo.bar". That may be true for a filesystem, but it's not true for S3. It's just a string with slashes in it.

Comment: you can try aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destinationbucket

Comment: You could also have a look at the [Benji](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/) lib (I'm contributor of) which support S3 ops (with reactive/streaming support).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Could you please suggest the best method to achieve it? I am working in a spark/scala application.

Comment: No, that's too much for just a "suggestion". You have a non-hierarchical object storage system, and you want to treat it like a filesystem. You need a proper design for it, or use an existing filesystem-like wrapper (which may *not* be an efficient solution, as objects in S3 cannot be renamed). It may be better to design your system differently. You need to research and narrow down the question.

Comment: You could have a look at https://zengularity.github.io/benji/ (I'm contributor) which offer some fs/object storage abstraction

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call to operate on whole directories in Amazon S3.

In fact, directories/folders do not exist in Amazon S3. Rather, each object stores the full path in its filename (`Key`).

If you wish to copy multiple objects that have the same prefix in their Key, your code will need to loop through the objects, copying one object at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A bit wordy, but does the job: reasonable logging, multithreading via TransferManager, handling continuation token for "folders" with more than 1000 keys:

```
/**
 * Copies all content from s3://sourceBucketName/sourceFolder to s3://destinationBucketName/destinationFolder.
 */
public void copyAll(String sourceBucketName, String sourceFolder, String destinationBucketName, String destinationFolder) {
    log.info("Copying data from s3://{}/{} to s3://{}/{}", sourceBucketName, sourceFolder, destinationBucketName, destinationFolder);
    TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
            .withS3Client(client)
            .build();

    try {
        ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
                .withBucketName(sourceBucketName)
                .withPrefix(sourceFolder);

        ListObjectsV2Result objects;
        do {
            objects = client.listObjectsV2(request);

            List<Copy> transfers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (S3ObjectSummary object : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
                String sourceKey = object.getKey();
                String sourceRelativeKey = sourceKey.substring(sourceFolder.length());
                String destinationKey = destinationFolder + sourceRelativeKey;

                transfers.add(transferManager.copy(sourceBucketName, sourceKey, destinationBucketName, destinationKey));
            }
            for (Copy transfer : transfers) {
                log.debug(transfer.getDescription());
                transfer.waitForCompletion();
            }

            log.info("Copied batch of {} objects. Last object: {}", transfers.size(), transfers.isEmpty() ? "None" : transfers.get(transfers.size() - 1).getDescription());
            request.setContinuationToken(objects.getNextContinuationToken());
        } while (objects.isTruncated());
        log.info("Copy operation completed successfully from s3://{}/{} to s3://{}/{}", sourceBucketName, sourceFolder, destinationBucketName, destinationFolder);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Resetting interrupt flag and returning control to the caller.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        transferManager.shutdownNow(false);
    }
}
```