# How to move/copy list of S3 Objects from one folder to folder in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy/move a list of S3 objects (all the S3 objects in a given folder) from one folder to another in the same bucket. I could write the code for on object as follows.

```
public static S3Response copySingleFile(S3Request s3Request) {
        S3Validation.validateCopyMoveArgs(s3Request);
        CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest=new CopyObjectRequest(s3Request.getBucketName(), s3Request.getSourcekey(), s3Request.getBucketName(), s3Request.getDestKey());
        AWSClient.getS3Client().copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
        return response;
    }
```

I think it should be done by making a list of object of that given folder and copy the list to the destination. I hope the logic is that but I'm in trouble in coding part.

Comment: What did it do when you tested it? What errors did you get?

Comment: This code is for single object. it works fine. I'm in trouble to modify the code for multiple objects.

Comment: Do you have to delete the original object ?

Comment: Check answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970836

Answer (score 1):

The `copyObject()` API call to Amazon S3 only allows one object to be copied. You will need to iterate through the list of objects and copy each object individually.

You will need a `listObjectsV2()` call to obtain the list of existing objects, then call `copyObject()` for each of them.